# PHP, получить JSON данные ответа через API сервиса

Tags: php, json

Уже всю голову сломал...
Есть API сервиса: https://turgenev.ashmanov.com/?a=apikey
Нужно получить ответ.

Делаю так:

```
//Получаем данные из формы, данные приходят, все нормально
$api = $_GET["api"];
$key = $_GET["key"];
$text = $_GET["text"];
$more = $_GET["more"];

//Если в адресную строку браузера вставить то, что возвращает $url, то все нормально
$url = "https://turgenev.ashmanov.com/?api=$api&key=$key&text=$text&more=$more";

$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"POST",
'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
          "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
)
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
var_dump($data);
```

Но $data возвращает false.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно получить то же, что и в браузере, то нет необходимости в контексте (обратите внимание, данные передаются в url по $_GET, а контекст - `'method' => "POST"`).

К тому же при обращении через `file_get_contents()` к URL его неплохо бы обернуть в `urlencode()`, чтобы правильно передавать пробелы и спецсимволы.

**Попробуйте так:**

```
$url = "https://turgenev.ashmanov.com/?api=$api&key=$key&text=$text&more=$more";
$url = urlencode($url);

$data = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($data);
```

Должно решить вашу проблему.

Если нет - напишите что вернул `var_dump()` в комментарии к ответу.

Comment: Спасибо. Не получается все равно. var_dump() вернул bool(false)

Comment: @DimyCH можете мне в whatsapp +7 904 689 20 81 скинуть данные API? Проверю.

Comment: Могу тут скинуть ключ:6b259cce07239b4dec47515ae2ad2308 (без пробелов на конце и вначале). В api кидайте risk, text - любой русский текст. В more значение 1

Comment: Вы знаете, вместо $text = $_GET["text"]; написал $text = urlencode($_GET["text"]); и заработало )))) Вот это тоже оставил $url = urlencode($url); Спасибо большое вам! Без вас бы не догадался! Ключ API сменил